# Number of ways of choosing $m$ elements from $p$ groups of elements with at most $k$ of one type

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's say we have $p$ groups of elements with $n_1$, $n_2$, $\dots$, $n_p$ items in the corresponding groups. The elements of the same group are identical.

We want to pick a total of $m$ elements from these $p$ groups of elements, following the condition that there could be at most $k$ elements which belong to the same type.

Is there a direct way to calculate the total number of ways to pick the $m$ elements following the given conditions?

Comment: Have you learned anything about generating functions?

Comment: I don't have any idea about generating functions. I'll look into it if it could be used to solve the problem.